Postgres store UUID in a column of type bit varying(16)
I have a table in my postgres database with a column of type bit varying (16). I need to store UUID in this column. Is it even possible to store UUID on 16 bits? If so, does postgres provide any sort of casting/anything helpful in this matter?

Why don't you use the UUID data type? See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html

Also you obviously can't store a uuid in 16 bits - it has more than 16 bits of data in its value.

See the documentation for UUID. You will notice that a uuid is a 128-bit quantity. So no it cannot be stored in 16 bits. Downvoting for no research.

No, a UUID won't fit into 16 bits. Use the uuid data type.
